# gatsby-image: don't see pictures in childImageSharp?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

This is probably a bit of a basic question but still can't nail down the concept of why I'm only able to see one file in this sample graphql query:

```
query {
  file {
    childImageSharp {
      id
      fluid {
        src
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but i'm able to see all my images listed in with this:

```
query MyQuery {
  allFile {
    nodes {
      childImageSharp {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone else what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure it's a configuration issue but not sure what the issue may be. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered at first according to the question title. After reading your question again, I realized that I didn't answer your question at all.

Your problem is not related to `childImageSharp`, it is related to the query you are using.

- The `file` query will ask for only one result.
- The `allFile` query will ask for all the results by default (you can add filters on it).

I advise learning a bit more about graphql, https://www.howtographql.com/ is quite popular.

### Here is my original answer

You can try something like this to see all the resolutions:

```
query {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "logo.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
          srcSet
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

you will get something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "file": {
      "childImageSharp": {
        "fluid": {
          "srcSet": "/static/320cb30c50318c089773e0770b96b2a2/d278e/logo.jpg 200w,\n/static/320cb30c50318c089773e0770b96b2a2/8539d/logo.jpg 400w,\n/static/320cb30c50318c089773e0770b96b2a2/bc3a8/logo.jpg 800w,\n/static/320cb30c50318c089773e0770b96b2a2/81ef8/logo.jpg 1200w,\n/static/320cb30c50318c089773e0770b96b2a2/989b1/logo.jpg 1600w,\n/static/320cb30c50318c089773e0770b96b2a2/96775/logo.jpg 9094w"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in gatsby we generaly use gatsby-image, so be sure to use the correct Fragments in the queries: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#fluid-queries

Answer (score 0):

To answer generally - both of the queries in your question are working as expected; there's no configuration issue.

The first query is always intended to return only one result. You can [provide parameters](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/) to control the result you get. You can see more information about the available parameters in the GraphQL schema for your Gatsby site.